# Can't connect with Remote Desktop Connection

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

I try to connect from work to my laptop in home via Remote Desktop Connection, but I can't.
On work I use PC with Windows 7, at home laptop is with Windows 7 + router.

In "System Properties" I checked "Allow Remote Assistance...", on Remote Desktop is second option "Allow Connections from computers running any version of RD".

Remote laptop has username+password.

Also I switch off Firewall on laptop and firewall on router just to try and nothing happen. Got message "Remote Desktop can`t connect to the remote computer..."

I'm really stuck on this and any help will be appreciated.

Comment: "at home laptop is with Windows 7"... Windows 7 what... Professional?  Ultimate?  Because you won't be able to RDP into Windows 7 Home Premium.  Just like XP Home and Vista Home Premium, Windows 7 Home Premium doesn't include all the necessary files to accept RDP connections.  Doesn't matter what the checkbox says.  You'd have to hack your version of Win 7 home to think it was Pro, and even then, some report that SP1 breaks the hack.  http://andrewblock.net/2010/02/23/enable-remote-desktop-on-windows-7-home-premium-64-32-bit

Comment: Home laptop is - Windows 7 Ultimate. Work PC is Windows 7 Proffesional. I`m sorry forgot to mention.

Comment: no problem.  Just making sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a NAT router, disabling the router firewall may not be enough. Did you set up a port forwarding rule?

To be able to connect to your laptop at home, you have to set up a port forwarding rule which forwards an external port of your choice to the internal port 3389 (remote desktop) of your laptop.

Let's say your external ip is 1.2.3.4 and the internal ip of your laptop is 192.168.0.20. You could then create the following forwarding rule:

`1.2.3.4:55555 -> 192.168.0.20:3389`

This would forward external port 55555 to the remote desktop port of your laptop.

If you correctly disabled the firewalls on your router and laptop, you should be able to get a remote desktop connection from work using 1.2.3.4:55555.

Comment: OK i will try this. What port i need to put on external- 55555 ? or other ?

Comment: I can't see where in router i can set this rules. Router is MSI RG54SE II. In menu 'Forwarding' i have 'Virtual Servers', 'Port Triggering', 'DMZ' and 'UPnP'

Comment: @JasonPaddle Go to _Virtual Servers_, add a new one. Then choose _Service Port_ 3389 and insert the internal ip of your laptop as _IP Address_. Choose TCP as _Protocol_ and _Status_ enabled. This way you will forward external port 3389 to internal port 3389 of your laptop.

Comment: done, but still no connection [Image](http://img822.imageshack.us/img822/5906/23125296.jpg)

Comment: @JasonPaddle You can try a port scan e.g. with [nmap](http://nmap.org/) to see if port 3389 is really open: If you get a _port filtered_ result, some firewall is still blocking. If you get a _port closed_ result, your port forwarding works and your firewalls are disabled, but your remote desktop service is not enabled.

Comment: Tried with this: [Online Scaner](http://www.t1shopper.com/tools/port-scan/result/) and got this message: IP isn't responding on port 3389 on both local and remnote PC's

Answer (score 0):

Do you have another machine you can connect to the network local to your home laptop and test the RDP connection from that machine to your laptop. That would test whether RDP is working at all on this pc and possibly point a finger at the router / firewall settings.

Comment: No, i have only one external and one remote